# Publish custom jar output with gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle build script that retrieves a number of common dependencies and creates a "fat jar" with them all combined.

> gradle fatJar uploadArchives

However the uploadArchives step afterwards does not use the jar generated and instead overwrites it with a default jar that has none of the dependencies.

How can I specify the publish step to use the "fat jar" and not overwrite the jar created?

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version '1.2.3'

sourceSets {
   main {
      resources.srcDirs = ["resources"]  
   }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
  runtime 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3.1'                            
  ....
  runtime 'xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0'

}


//create a single Jar with all dependencies
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Some common jars',  
            'Implementation-Version': version
    }
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}



uploadArchives {
   repositories {

      mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/org-sandbox") {
            authentication(userName: "admin", password:"password")
        }
        pom.groupId = 'org.something'
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: do you want to publish both jars? or only the fat one? BTW, gradle has a newer [`maven-publish`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin which handles customization a bit better than the `maven` plugin you're using.

Comment: Only the fat one.... watching the process the maven jar overwrites the jar created by the fatJar step.

Comment: You could always change one of their filenames..

Answer (score 6):

Following RaGe's suggestion, I switched to `maven-publish`, which allows specifying the artifact by task name.  This worked.

```
    publishing {
      publications {
         maven(MavenPublication) {
       
           groupId 'org.something'
       
           artifact fatJar 
        }
     }
  
     repositories { 
      maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/sandbox"
        credentials { 
           username 'admin' 
           password 'password' 
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

RaGe (responder to OP) is correct that there is a new 'maven-publish' plugin.

An excellent and complete example can be found [here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/publishing/#publishing-with-maven-publish-plugin).

My working implementation is here:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.thingspan:objydb-core:13.6.0'

    implementation 'au.com.bytecode:opencsv:2.4'

    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.8.0-beta1'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.8.0-beta1'
    implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
}

assemble.dependsOn("shadowJar")

shadowJar {
    configurations = [project.configurations.compileClasspath]
    zip64 true
}

publishing {
  publications {
    shadow(MavenPublication) { 
        publication -> project.shadow.component(publication)
    }
  }
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
  }
}
```